# Why converted values from Decimal to binary isn't the same?

Tags: binary, decimal-expansion, chinese-remainder-theorem

the professor told us today about binary and decimal and how to convert them , and give us example of a decimal number (13) and we converted it to binary which is (1101) .

Now when I'm trying to do the same way with number (19) I found the binary is (10011) and to check it up I try to convert binary back to decimal , so when I try to do that it gives me a wrong number (not 19) so what's wrong ? I double check it and I even used an online tool to see if I got the binary wrong .

any help please , my brain on fire :D

Thanks in advance .

Comment: You are not converting it to decimal correctly

Comment: @DavidPeterson I'm sure I did it correctly , I double check it and used online tool as I mentioned , it gives me the same binary I got by myself but when I'm converting it back to decimal it's something wrong , I can send you img of my answer if this helps. 
[REF](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-decimal.html)

Comment: When i type in 10011 it says 19...

Comment: $10011_2=2^4+0+0+2^1+2^0=19$

Comment: Show your work on your binary to decimal conversion, either an image or just in text in your question.

Comment: I'm so sorry guys I figured out what's wrong , my bad , should I delete the question or do what ?

Comment: Saber Hosney I would leave it up. Click the check mark on memerson's answer to close out the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does give 19. $10011$ in base 2 is equal to $1(2^0)+1(2^1)+0(2^2)+0(2^3)+1(2^4)=
1(2^0)+1(2^1)+1(2^4)=1(1)+1(2)+1(16)=1+2+16=19$.

Comment: Oh , I thought I'm adding the binary number plus the base  like 1+16 not just 16 !